# Connect WordPress website to remote MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress website hosted on GoDaddy and obviously the website content is stored on WordPress's MySQL. Now I want to change this database to my remote MySQL database. 
Is it possible to get the whole script of WordPress database (all tables with stored content) and run it on my remote database? Then I change the connection string from `wp-config.php` by providing my remote database details.

Would this procedure work and will my work done remain available?

Comment: Remote database? As I know, please just connect via PhpMyadmin via their Control Panel to manage your database.

Comment: I have a cloud server which this remote MySQL database installed and I would like to add wordpress's database tables with a particular database on my cloud server, is it possible?

Comment: And, did you try it?!

Comment: I believe there is no problem. You can try it to connect via PhpMyadmin to manage your database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this wouldn't be a problem. Go into phpMyAdmin in your control panel and export the database. Import it into your remote DB. Then update wp-config.php with your remote DB details.

Answer (score 0):

This is built into wordpress.
Just login to wordpress, go to tools > export. Select all content, and save the file.
Then locally, click tools > Import.

Answer (score 0):

By exporting the database and importing into the other location you cannot possibly ruin anything, so don't be afraid, just export the data, import it where it is needed and change your configuration. Do not be afraid to try out things when you cannot ruin anything.